# How do I crop and center a full-height image when I don't know the container's dimensions?

Tags: html, css, image

There are a few questions out there that show how to crop and center images, but I haven't found one that matches these requirements:

- The visible part of the image must be square.
- The image should be scaled so that the full height is displayed and fills the height of the container.
- The size of the container is variable and determined by the width of it's container.
- The image must be centered.

The end-goal is to have a grid with 3 square images in a row that shrink depending on the browser width.

Here's what I have so far.

```css
.i-om-section-content {
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 32px;
  padding: 0 3.2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.i-om-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 32.5%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 32.5%;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="i-om-section-content">
  <div class="i-om-item">
    <img src="http://onetaste.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DSC2641.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="i-om-item">
    <img src="http://onetaste.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/smita.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asciiman/j9tksfjL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want more advance cropping/positioning/sizing of images, it's much easier to work with them as background images. `background-size:auto 100%` means "auto width, full height," the rest of it was what you already had.

```
<div class="i-om-section-content">
    <div class="i-om-item one">
    </div>
    <div class="i-om-item two">
    </div>
</div>
```

--

```
.i-om-section-content {
    max-width: 800px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 32px;
    padding: 0 3.2rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.i-om-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 32.5%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 32.5%;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    background-size:center center;
}
.one{
    background-image:url("http://onetaste.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DSC2641.png");
}
.two{
    background-image:url("http://onetaste.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/smita.png");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ammsh4y5/

Comment: Thank you!  And I forgot to add that the image must be centered.  I'll update the description.

Answer (score 1):

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9tksfjL/2/).

It uses jQuery to set the height and width of the container to be the same (make it square). It then sets the image height to the height of the div. Lastly, it centers the image by getting the difference of the widths of the image and the div, dividing it by two, and moving it that much left (absolute positioning).

Here's the jQuery code (CSS and HTML were modified as well):

```
function updateImage() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.height(parent.width()); 
        $(this).height(parent.height());
        $(this).css("left", -($(this).width()-parent.width())/2);
    });
}

// call on window resize and on load
$(window).resize(function() {
    updateImage();
});
updateImage();
```

It's not the most elegant solution but it does the job and is pretty intuitive. (But I do like @DylanWatt's `background-image` solution: much more creative).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.i-om-section-content {
    max-width: 800px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 32px;
    padding: 0 3.2rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.i-om-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 32.5%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 32.5%;
    border: 1px solid;
 
     display:inline-block;    
    background-position:center center;
}
.one{
    background-image:url("http://onetaste.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DSC2641.png");
}
.two{
    background-image:url("http://onetaste.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/smita.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="i-om-section-content">
    <div class="i-om-item one">
    </div>
    <div class="i-om-item two">
    </div>
</div>
```